# Unable to call a service method from controller in my custom plugin

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, controller, services

I know there are similar questions here, but I don't see a definitive answer, nor one that works for me.

I've generated a plugin via pluginfactory.io, which has some controllers and a single service.

I can call the controllers in the CP without issue - if I just return a 'Hello world' from any of the controller methods, it works.

But when I follow the example supplied in the code comments (for the service file) inside of my controller action:

```
MyPluginName::$plugin->importer->exampleService()
```

I get an exception:

> Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException
>   Getting unknown property: amphibian\mypluginname\MyPluginName::Importer

I have a service file called `Importer` in my `services` folder, with a class name of `Importer`, and a method named `exampleService()`.

The `extra` section of my `composer.json` file lists:

```
"components": {
    "importer": "amphibian\\mypluginname\\services\\Importer"
}
```

What else am I missing?

Comment: Did you change the content of the `composer.json` after you installed the plugin by chance? Maybe you added the service afterwards or change the name of the service? Added this line after you ran `composer update`?

Comment: Based on the info provided, what @RobinSchambach says above is most likely the issue – which means that uninstalling, then re-installing the plugin will probably resolve the issue. I've been bit by this before; it's one of the reasons I'm not a fan of sticking the component config in `composer.json`, I feel that using the [`setComponents()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-di-servicelocator#setComponents()-detail) method from the plugin's `init` method is by far the cleaner option.

Comment: Unfortunately, nope - I did no renaming or manual edits. This is happening via files directly downloaded from the plugin generator.

Comment: I'm out of ideas other than if you want to zip up the plugin and attach it so we can try.

Comment: Had exactly the same issue with a pluginfactory generated plugin and eventually followed the setComponents instructions here: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/extend/services.html#creating-a-service